# problema con expresión regular validar formato

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

hola gente una duda quería ver si podían ayudarme con esta expresión regular

pasa que estoy creando un compilador, y ahorita estoy evaluando si unas cadenas cumplen con un formato usando esta expresión

```
(.*) [:][=] [0-9]*;$
```

Sagun yo la idea con esto es que acepté cualquier cadena (.*) o carácter lo que sera no importa porque esa validación la hice en una parte, pero aquí viene el detalle

ocupo que si o si la cadena que estoy evaluando tenga [:][=] y aparte tenga números del 0 al 9 pero la expresión no me funciona si pongo

esther:=45667;

variable2 := 0;

me entienden busco que se valide algo así pero no me funciona me ayudarían por favor

**lo que necesito es que se ingrese cualquier nombre con lo que sea, no importa si es una caracter solo, luego que tenga := luego numeros y ultimo punto y coma**

me hice esta expresion

```
(.*)[:=][0-9]*[;]
```

pero solo funciona en el regexr y no en netbeans 8.2

Comment: Los corchetes no son necesarios para : y =, lo que buscas es una cadena compuesta de cualquier caracter, seguida de := y luego una serie de numeros?

Comment: si exacto asi mismo

Comment: te molestaria ayudarme, tengo que entregar un proyecto pasado mañana jeje

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ asi como dices  lo que buscas es una cadena compuesta de cualquier caracter, seguida de := y luego una serie de numeros y finalizar con punto y coma

Comment: Hola Esther, algo así te serviría ***`.{1,}(:=){1}[\\d]{1,}(;){1}`*** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba la siguiente regex (link [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/ZKDNpb/1)):

```
"(.+)\s?:=\s?([0-9]+);"gm
```

busca un patron que cumpla con:

`(.+)` una serie de caracteres cualquiera con longitud de 1 a ∞

`\s?` un espacio opcional

`:=` contenga los caracteres ':=' en ese orden

`\s`? un espacio opcional

`([0-9]+);` una serie de enteros con longitud de 1 a ∞, seguido de ;

Debes tener cuidado en usar el comodín (.) porque eso incluye cualquier caracter que exista excepto el salto de linea, sobre todo si lo combinas con cuantificadores 'codiciosos' como + o * que tomaran la cadena más larga posible y producirán resultados no deseados sobre todo si la expresión se hace más larga, por ejemplo imagina que evaluo la siguiente cadena con el regex que te pase:

```
A:=1; B:=2;
```

esto produce una coincidencia, en lugar de 2, y eso se debe al comodín en combinación el cuantificador '+', por eso te recomiendo no utilizar los comodines ni los cuantificadores codiciosos a menos que sea estrictamente necesario, mejor utiliza rangos {} y especifica los tipos de caracteres para que la regex sea lo más restrictiva posible

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono

Comment: @EstherPorta marca la respuesta como aceptada, harias muy feliz a un anonimo

Comment: a si perdon muchas gracias mas bien